# MPMoviePlayerViewController works, MPMoviePlayerController does not..why?

Tags: iphone, media-player, ios5

I have this code

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"d" ofType:@"mp4"];  
NSURL    *url    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  

//part 1
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  
//[player prepareToPlay];
//[player setShouldAutoplay:YES];
//[player setControlStyle:2];
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
[player play];

//part2
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mp];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

the part2 works, part1 not...they are using the same url and I've almost copyed and pasted the  snippet from the ADC site

I'm using ios5

Comment: Thanks for including Part 2.  Have only seen the Part 1 code around and it's been driving me crazy as it just doesn't work.  Part 2 code works great!

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since this question was posted, but the answer is that you must keep a reference of the `MPMoviePlayerController` variable.

If you have the code of part1 in a function, declare `MPMoviePlayerController *player` in your .h file. If you don't do that (and your are developing with `ARC`) your player variable will be deallocated as soon as you exit the function. Notice that your are adding `player.view` to `self.view`, so the player's view gets retained, but the player's controller does not and it gets deallocated.

So your should have in your .h file:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player;
```

and in this case, your function must be something like:

```
-(void) playMovie
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                         pathForResource:@"mymovie" 
                                         ofType:@"mov"]];    

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    [player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  
    [self.view addSubview: player.view];
    [player play];        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on iOS 5 with MPPlayerController and I have checked Apple's example project, the difference was only setting frame so I set frame manually and it worked perfectly.

```
    [[[self moviePlayer] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't add the player view to the main view until the video is not loaded.

So you should replace this line :

```
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
```

By this one :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(movieLoadStateDidChange:) 
    name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
    object:player];
```

And add this method:

```
-(void)movieLoadStateDidChange: (NSNotification*)notification{
    if (player.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            removeObserver:self 
            name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
            object:player] ; 
        [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: MPMovieLoadStatePlayable == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable ?? What's this?